# In which range will run WorkManager if I set it at 09:00?

Tags: android-workmanager

I need to execute function at 09:00 every morning. I know about AlarmManager but I want to use WorkManager. In which range will run this code?
+- 10 minutes? have anyone tried it? I don't use any constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to run your Work at exactly 9:00AM, WorkManager may not be the best option for you.

The Period you set in WorkManager, for a periodic Worker it's a minimum value however, if a device is in doze mode, your work will not be run till the next execution window.
Given that you cannot specify a a time of the day to run your Work, but only an interval (let's say 24 hours). The time the Work will be executed will slip day after day.

So, at it is right now, a plain PeriodicWorkRequest may not be the best option for your use case.

An alternative is to use a OneTimeWorkRequest that schedule itself the next day using an initial dalay that you compute in your Worker:

```
class DailyWorker(ctx: Context, params: WorkerParameters) : Worker(ctx, params) 
{
    override fun doWork(): Result {
        // Do Something

        val now = LocalTime.now()
        val nineAM = LocalTime.parse("09:00:00")
        val timeDiff = Duration.ofHours(24).minus(Duration.between(nineAM, now))
        val dailyWorkRequest = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<DailyWorker>()
                .setInitialDelay(timeDiff)
                .addTag(TAG_OUTPUT)
                .build()
        WorkManager.getInstance(applicationContext).enqueue(dailyWorkRequest)

        return Result.success()
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to know in which range will it run at least. For example, if I put 09:00 what is the maximum amount of time for it to run if it delayed?

Comment: thanks for the answer but setInitialDelay(timeDiff) requires API level 26, my minimum is 23. how to downgrade?